# what's the equivalent of copy con <filename> in linux/bash

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal

In DOS/Windows, we can do the following on the command prompt

```
copy con [filename] <ENTER>
```

this will copy whatever you enter into the terminal into the filename.

Now, what's the equivalent of this in bash/linux ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several such commands. A literal translation exists, but usually the Linux equivalent of "more > somefile" is preferred as it is much shorter to type than the "copy con" equivalent.

1. The conventional way to create files is by using `>` output redirection (same as in Windows) together with `cat` (which is roughly like DOS `type` or `more`).

   When invoked without any filename, 'cat' will read from its "standard input" by default, allowing **`cat > somefile`** to create a file from keyboard input (like `more > somefile` on Windows).
2. The literal translation of `CON` on Linux is **`/dev/tty`** (representing the "current terminal").

   Running **`cp /dev/tty somefile`** (or `cat /dev/tty > somefile`) would copy from the terminal exactly as your DOS command does.

   (Linux also has a special path representing the program's stdin. Running `cp /dev/stdin somefile` would read from the standard input, almost the same way as `cat > somefile`.)

In both cases, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> is the EOF key, equivalent to Ctrl-Z in Windows or DOS.

Comment: Hi @user1686, thank you. I didn't know that "more > filename" works on windows! It is a great answer. Thanks again.